# how to send data or message from java application / plugin to javascript with cordova / phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I think I'm missing something here. I'm used to sending data from javascript to java and back with calls to execute and back with the callbackContext methods.

But if at some points, lets say I have a running thread that needs to send data to the javascript at regular intervals, how should I do that then ? (This assumes that this task is running and has not been triggered by a javascript action, thus no callbackContext is available)

Comment: Which platform(s) does your plugin support?

Comment: For now, only android. I hope to support ios as well in the coming months

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always execute javascript from java doing this:

```
String js = "alert('test')";
webView.loadUrlNow("javascript:" + js);
```

Or you can init the plugin and keep the callback doing this

```
PluginResult pgRes = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "message");
pgRes.setKeepCallback(true);
callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pgRes);
```

Added example provided by Sephy

```
private String myCbkId;
// Store callbackId from a call to execute 
@Override public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray arr, CallbackContext cbkCtx) throws JSONException { 

    myCbkId = cbkCtx.getCallbackId(); 
    JSONObject data = arr.getJSONObject(0); 
    String ack = data.getString("data"); // You can acknowledge to the callback for instance and keep it alive 
    Log.d(TAG, "ack".equals(ack) ? "ack !" : "not ack !");

    // These lines can be reused anywhere in your app to send data to the javascript
    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, ack);
    result.setKeepCallback(true);//This is the important part that allows executing the callback more than once, change to false if you want the callbacks to stop firing  
    this.webView.sendPluginResult(result, this.myCbkId); 

    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's kinda what I ended doing but this needs some explaining and more details for people who come accross this answer to get the point. I'll publish my solution later to compare it to yours.

Comment: Which one needs more explanation? first one is trivial, is the way you execute javascript from java. Second part maybe needs some explanation, but your question was vague too, it seemed you just needed orientation, you didn't ask for a complete example

Comment: Here is my complete solution. If it's ok with you to publish it in your answer as a more detailled version, I'll check your answer. Thanks for the pointer !

Comment: // Store callbackId from a call to execute
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray arr, CallbackContext cbkCtx) throws JSONException {
        myCbkId = cbkCtx.getCallbackId();
        JSONObject data = arr.getJSONObject(0);
        String ack = data.getString("data");
        // You can acknowledge to the callback for instance and keep it alive
        Log.d(TAG, "ack".equals(ack) ? "ack !" : "not ack !");

Comment: // These lines can be reused anywhere in your app to send data to the javascript        
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, ack);
        result.setKeepCallback(true);
        this.webView.sendPluginResult(result, this.myCbkId);

        return true;
    }

Comment: np. Hope this will help people passing by.

Comment: how do you receive the pluginResult "message" on the cordova / javascript side?

Comment: when you call the plugin function from js, one of the params is the callback, the function you pass as callback will be executed every time the native code is executed

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is communication from server to client in asynchronous way than websockets are the solution for you. Exact implementation depends on which web server you use so you'd net to give more details but they all work same way more or less.

Comment: I'm not sure you got my issue well, I'm trying to talk between my java plugin and my web application wrapped with cordova...I'm not trying to do HTTP/WS communication.

Comment: Right sorry. Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852499/javascript-calls-from-android-using-phonegap

Comment: Didn't see this one before you mention it, thx. But 1) it's a bi outdated as off Cordova 3, some things changed with plugins. 2) This question is not really clear to me and does not provide a clear and generic solution to reuse when you want to communicate from java to js with Cordova/Phonegap. If I understand it well, it mainly explains how to communicate from js to java, which I already know how to do.